# nodejs: Koa , form in pug gives undefined

Tags: node.js, pug, koa

I have a form in pug with just one input

```
form(action="/" method="POST")
 label Enter URL to shorten
 br
 input(name="url" type="url") 
 button(type="submit") Submit
```

I use koa-pug to get the input

```
async function handleForm (ctx) {
   console.log(ctx.request.body);
}
```

However this logs undefined

I also use koa-body as body parser

```
app.use(body());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form, you are calling your koa backend with a `POST` method. So to get the body, you need to use something like `co-body`,

```
...
const parse = require('co-body');
...

async function handleForm (ctx) {
  let body = await parse(ctx);
  console.log(body);
}
```

Comment: I was using koa-body as body parser and I replaced it with co-body as you suggested and it works now.

Comment: I would recommend using [koa-bodyparser](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser). You just need to do `app.use(bodyParser())` once in your main file, and then you'll have access to `ctx.request.body` in your request handlers.

Comment: One other note: It's possible that the module you were using before isn't working because of the wrong version. A lot of middleware authors have different versions for Koa v1 and Koa v2. Since you're using Koa v2 here, you would have to have done `npm install koa-body@2` instead of just `npm install koa-body`. Some middleware is 2 by default sometimes you have to opt-in. It's a good idea to look at the github repo or readme so you know.

Comment: I'd installed the right version of koa-body , it wasn't working because I called after router instead of before.